# Bind multiple view models in KnockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to work out how I bind multiple models from a master model to different parts of my HTML mark up. The HTML part is:-

```
   <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: members}">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: MemberId"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: SwagCompany"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: SwagThing"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

<span data-bind="text: winner.Name"></span>
```

But can't work out how to bind the `winner.Name`, my model looks like this:-

```
var masterViewModel = {
   vmA : { ...},
   vmB : { ... }
}

ko.applyBindings({
      winner: ko.observable(masterViewModel.vmB),
      members: ko.observableArray(mappedData),
      ...
    }
```

Obviously I am misunderstanding how to applyBindings correctly. I have the following code as a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/W3NTrh4ZMM4kPbC77ClY/preview) showing an example of what I am trying to do:-

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var masterViewModel = {
        vmA: function memberViewModel(data) {
            this.Id = data.MemberId;
            this.MemberId = ko.observable(data.MemberId);
            this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
            this.SwagCompany = ko.observable("");
            this.SwagThing = ko.observable("");
            this.Photo = ko.observable(data.Photo);
        },
        vmB: {
            Name: "Initial winner..."
        }
    };

    $.getJSON("/home/memberlist")
        .then(function (rawData) {
            return ko.utils.arrayMap(rawData, function (instanceData) {
                return new masterViewModel.vmA(instanceData);
            });
        })
        .done(function (mappedData) {
            doit(mappedData);
        });

    function doit(mappedData) {
        ko.applyBindings({
            winner: ko.observable(masterViewModel.vmB),
            members: ko.observableArray(mappedData),
            getNextWinner: function () {
                var members = this.members();
                var winner = this.winner();
                //console.log(ddd.Name());
                $.getJSON("/home/nextwinner")
                    .then(function (rawData) {
                        var nextWinner = ko.utils.arrayFirst(members, function (member) {
                            return member.Id === rawData.Winner.MemberId;
                        });
                        nextWinner.SwagThing(rawData.WonSwag.Thing);
                        nextWinner.SwagCompany(rawData.WonSwag.Company);
                        winner.Name(rawData.Winner.Name);
                    });
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I agree with @xdumaine's answer. If you're applying the MVVM pattern correctly you should only need to create and bind a view model once. Rather than trying to change the content of the page by re-binding to a new view model instance, you should be able to simply modify the view model instance that was bound when the page was loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is very messy, as you're creating a viewModel object within your applybindings call, and creating viewModel objects directly. Use the constructor syntax, and create new instances of your viewmodels. All you need to do for `applyBindings` is give it a single instance of your master view model.

Use [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NL45/) as an example, and try to keep your code structured and organized, or it will get extremely messy very quickly.

```
// this is like a constructor for your members
var memberViewModel = function memberViewModel(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.Id = data.MemberId;
   self.MemberId = ko.observable(data.MemberId);
   self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
};

// This is like a constructor for your master view model
var masterViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.Members = ko.observableArray();

   // put two members into Members
   self.Members.push(new memberViewModel({MemberId: 1, Name: 'Member1'}));
   self.Members.push(new memberViewModel({MemberId: 2, Name: 'Member2'}));

   // set the winner to the first one for default, if you want
   self.Winner = ko.observable(self.Members()[0]);

   //do your ajax in this function
   self.GetNextWinner = function() {
     self.Winner(self.Members()[1]);
   }
};

//Apply bindings gets one instance of your view model
ko.applyBindings(new masterViewModel());
```

Comment: Great, one quick question if Winner was split into several properties would you introduce a second view model or would you do something like `self.Winner` ... `Self.WinnerSwag` ... `self.WinnerSwagThing` and then in the `GetNextWinner` function set each one manually?

Comment: @Rippo If I understand correctly, it really shouldn't matter, you could just keep those on the master view model, or split them into a separate object. I'm inclined to say keep them in the master view model, unless they are all a part of a single object entity. It looks like those properties are really for UI display/action, in which case they should go in the master view model.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I am saying Winner has around 6 properties and from a C# perspective I would create a child class called winner and have `Winner.Name` and `Winner.Photo` and `Winner.DOB` etc etc. So you are saying I can create a separate child object called `Winner` ?

Comment: @Rippo Yeah, definitely, it makes sense for that. Properties *of* the Winner should be on their own `Winner` object, but properties *for* the winner shouldn't - something like a property that holds a string for the instructions, or a button click handler.